# ERROR in Error:module.exports = ReferenceError: module is not defined webpack.config .js configuration

Tags: webpack

To solve ERROR: webpack://webpack-demo/data:text/javascript,**webpack_public_path**_=***webpack_base_ur  i***=_htmlWebpackPluginPublicPath;?:2
module.exports = **webpack_require**.p + "aed5664e42105e46cf2a61b59786988d.bin";
^
ReferenceError: module is not defined
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cpnh8.png)

```
 const {resolve} = require('path'); 
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
  entry: './src/index.js',
  output: {
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    path: resolve(__dirname, 'dist')
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader']
      },
      {
        exclude: /\.(css|js|html)$/,
        loader: require.resolve('file-loader')
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: './src/index.html'
    })
  ],
  mode: 'development'
};
```

[image: dependencies]

I found a solution

> exclude: /.(css|js|html)$/,
> type: 'asset/resource'

[image]

Comment: please make sure you have Webpack installed on your computer. you have to install other plugins like html-webpack-plugin, css-loader, style-loader, file-loader

Comment: Of course, I have all of these installed

Comment: I found a solution
webpack5 can use asset module type instead of file-loader, etc.
The resource module type replaces the Loader by adding four new module types
1. asset /resource sends a separate file and exports the URL instead of the file-loader
2. asset /inline exports the data URL of a resource instead of the URL-loader
3. asset /source everywhere source code, previously implemented by using raw-loader.
4. asset has a choice between exporting a data URL and sending a separate file, previously done with the URL-loader +limit property.

Comment: why are your file-loader and style-loader and css-loader is such a low version. install 
    "css-loader": "^5.2.4",
    "file-loader": "^6.2.0",
    "style-loader": "^2.0.0",

Comment: I've used your webpack config in a test project and have worked like a charm. I think by using the upstream version of the packages your issue would solve.

Comment: I installed these loaders following a learning video, but I don't know why the version is so low, it should be the latest version in theory, thanks for your answer, I also found a solution, updated in the comments and posts